# Allow user to change app notification sound

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have an app that uses Firebase Messaging to send notifications, and I have a set of sounds added to my xcode project resources, to play on the device.

I send the notification to users subscribed to specific topics, from my server like this:

```js
"apns": {
    "headers": {
        "apns-priority": "10",
    },
    "payload": {
        "aps": {
            "alert": {
                "title": titleMessage,
                "body": bodyMessage,
            },
            "sound": 'alert.wav',
        },
    },
}
```

Now the sound **"alert.wav"** plays fine on the device, when the notification is received.

What I want to do is inside my app:
**I want to allow users to change the notification sound, from different sets of sounds.**

**Example:** Option to play sound from: set 1, or set 2. and I would have them in my app as seperate folders with the same file names.

Is this possible in iOS? and how can I achieve it in react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it, and this is how:

**1. Added the sounds file in xcode, in my app resources.**

[image]
Just added a link to the folder that contains all my sounds, and did not link each file, as I want the app to play sounds later from: The "`/Library/Sounds` directory".

**2. Used rn-fetch-blob to copy sounds and replace them.**

By using ***rn-fetch-blob*** I was able to create the `/Library/Sounds` directory and then move the sounds from `MainBundleDir` to `/Library/Sounds`, where the app will be looking for sounds when a notification is received.

I created an interface to allow users to replace these sounds.

```
//Function: setup sounds
setupSounds(){
    //sounds directory
    const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
    const soundsDir = dirs.CacheDir.replace('Caches','Sounds')

    //Check if has sounds directory
    RNFetchBlob.fs.isDir(soundsDir).then((isDir) => {
        //create directory
        if(!isDir) RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(soundsDir)
    })

    //Add the sound file to /Library/Sounds
    RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(soundsDir+'/default.wav', dirs.MainBundleDir + '/sounds/jingle.wav', 'uri');
}
```

Now if the app received a notification with `sound: 'default.wav'` the app will play `default.wav` which is a copy of `jingle.wav`.